# Concatenate rows & then get distinct values

Tags: mysql

I have the following columns in my table: alias, first, last. I would like to concatenate the rows & then search for distinct values:
i.e.

1. jimmyWho, Jim, Smith
2. BallyHo, Bob, Smith
3. JimmytwoShoes, Jim, Smith
4. Bobtastic, Bob, Johnson
5. JimmytwoShoes, Jim, Smith
6. BallyHo, Dave, Jones

I would like to have the following results (notice that #5 above is a duplicate):

1. jimmyWho, Jim, Smith
2. BallyHo, Bob, Smith
3. JimmytwoShoes, Jim, Smith
4. Bobtastic, Bob, Johnson
5. BallyHo, Dave, Jones

In other words, I need to concatenate the rows & then search for distinct values only AFTER I've concatenated...doing so b/f the concatenation would not give the desired results. Is there a way to do this in Mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is entirely applicable to your situation but you should read up on the group_concat function to see if it meets your needs.  The query might look like

select distinct group_concat(column) from table where whaterver group by commonColumn.

Comment: You will almost always want to concatenate only distinct values, like this:
`SELECT key1, key2, group_concat(distinct column order by column separator ',') FROM table GROUP BY key1,key2`

Answer (score 5):

Check out `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT alias, first, last FROM users;
```

I don't understand your reason behind the concatenation. However, if the above doesn't work you can concatenate the records with `CONCAT()`

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(alias, ', ', first, ', ', last) FROM users;
```

Comment: Very nice. +1, but maybe a link? (Feel free to take the one from my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to link to the MySQL manual, but couldn't find a page specific to `DISTINCT`. No need to copy, you supplied a fine link.

Comment: ur second sample was so useful for me :B

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking for, you could do a query similar to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(all the columns or whatever) FROM table
```

See more [about select distinct](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)